# Why don't python3 inline if statements raise a SyntaxError, when whitespace after the if is omitted?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.6

The following statements in Python 3.6 and up to version 3.8 do not raise a SyntaxError, which  Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 do.

```
>>> ifNone: print(5)
5

>>> ifTrue: print('a')
a

>>> ifnotNone: print('foo')
foo
```

Note as well that no ellipsis is shown before the print statement is executed. Normally inline if statements have the following structure.

```
>>> if True: print('bar')
...
bar

>>> if False: print(10)
...
>>>
```

What allows this behaviour?

Comment: In Python 3.6+ it’s being treated as a [type hint](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#type-hints-cheat-sheet-python-3).

Answer (score 1):

The 1st example is probably declaring a variable called ifNone to be of type print(5).

Recall that PEP484 and PEP526 type annotations are just comments to the Python interpreter; you need something like mypy to make sense of them.